# comment reputation or weight

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

I"m sure someone has suggested this before but I couldn't find any threads on it.

I'm wondering if we should have a comment weight or comment rep on stack overflow. Right now you can get upvotes on a comment. Generally people use that to agree with a comment. But there doesn't seem to be a total for upvotes of comments.

I wonder if there could be any value to having something like that?

** EDIT**  "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: [Because it's free!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91808/please-downvote-me-its-free-now)

Comment: @mcgrailm downvotes have a different meaning on Meta than they have on SO: They are merely an expression of disagreement here.

Comment: so its not that its not a good question just that its a bad idea ?

Comment: @mcgrailm well, it means that 3 people don't agree with it, and don't want to see it implemented.

Comment: Thanks for all rhe down votes I am now discouraged from asking my questions

Comment: You shouldn't be discouraged from asking questions here because they get downvoted. As @Pekka explained, downvotes on meta simply mean that people *disagree* with your feature request. For example, I just downvoted, because I don't think comments should influence your reputation in any way. That doesn't mean I have anything against you, your ability to write a question, or even think you should stop asking them in the future!

Comment: common keep going I'll have 0 rep soo whoohoo! I can't delete the dammed thing now either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of StackOverflow is not the comments, the value is the answers and, to a lesser extent, the questions. While comments can be informative or entertaining, we're here to provide answers.

Keep the points on what matters.

You can, of course, earn a limited number of badges based upon your commenting activity.

Comment: i like that answer ! I don't like free downvotes though