# How can I find an old frozen chat room, rather than create a new one each time?

Tags: support, chat, frozen-rooms

Some time ago, upon mutual agreement, I created a chat with another user to ask for advice which would be off-topic in the Q&A page. Is there a way I can keep track of this chatroom? I tried to find it again after two or three weeks but

1. I have no idea how to search for it
2. I hesitate to create another room each time. I found this post ([Avoiding making so many new chatrooms called “Discussion between user[A] and user [B]” which later become frozen or not very useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353643/avoiding-making-so-many-new-chatrooms-called-discussion-between-usera-and-use)) very reasonable.

I also was sad to lose the discussion I had with the other user some time ago, I thought it would stay archived there somehow. And maybe it did, but I don't know how to find it. Is there a way?

Comment: You don't have 10K rep on Chat.SE?

Comment: I don't have 10K anywhere on SE :-)

Comment: Hmm, with 10K you would be able to see frozen rooms.

Comment: you do have > 10K chat rep. All rep of all sites gets combined / added

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that...

Comment: On a side note: This is exactly why chat isn't a way to circumvent the topic restrictions on these sites, and why it is better to write on-topic questions and answers on either main or meta sites: The information on these sites can be (re-)found by visitors and won't be 'lost' in chat. That said, you can also [bookmark chat conversations](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) and they should show up on [your chat profile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1038222/fev?tab=conversations), under the 'conversations' tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Starring rooms and showing frozen/deleted rooms

If you have 10k or more network wide reputation, you can see deleted rooms when you search for them:

[image]

<sub>Taken from just a rooms page, not a search page. Should still be there any time you search for rooms [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all)</sub>

If you remember roughly the name of the room, or text in the description, this should work.

---

If you were the owner of the room, you can see it on your [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/489057/fev). Again, only users with 10k or more network wide rep can see deleted rooms.

---

If you want to keep the room very close on hand, rather than searching for it each time, you can star the room:

[image]

This allows you to find it much more easily [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=favorite&sort=active), but can also mean that you'll join the room whenever you rejoin all your starred rooms.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response. These are very helpful tips I will certainly use in the future!

Answer (score 6):

If you were an owner of the chatroom, it will be listed on your chat user's profile page. [Here is yours](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/489057/fev). If there was [enough activity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) (more than 15 messages by at least 2 users) it won't have been deleted, simply frozen after a period of inactivity.

If you have at least 10k network rep you'll be able to see deleted rooms there as well. I can see 2 frozen and 5 deleted rooms which you're a Room Owner of.

Another method is searching for messages you remember which were in that room. For example, if you remembered that you discussed pasta in this room, you could search for [messages containing "pasta"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=489057&q=pasta) that you've posted, and that might help you find the room. (Assuming chat search is working, that is. It needs kicking some of the time)

Comment: Thank you, that really works. I am relatively new to SE and am still discovering it. I had no idea I had 10K rep and a chat profile! Super good to know.

Comment: @fev we've all been there! What helped me was reading through [[tag:faq]] posts (as needed or whenever I was interested) and badgering/asking experienced users in chat :) Wishing you luck on your SE journey!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The first wave I got here on meta was rather negative so I perceived it as a rather aggressive environment. But you proved me wrong so thanks! I wish I could accept both answers...