# (How) is the covid-19 situation affecting the 1Q20 timeline/roadmap?

Tags: support, community, company

[The Q1 2020 Community Roadmap is on the Blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344178/the-q1-2020-community-roadmap-is-on-the-blog) gave a dense timeline, with plenty of actions planned by SE Inc. to happen in March 2020.

That post was written 20 days ago, and for many people (at least those in the Western hemisphere), the world probably felt very much different 20 days back.

So, just for our own expectation management: do you currently intend to follow up on that initial plan, or have circumstances changed for you in ways that will require staging, delays, significant changes, ...?

---

<sub>Please don't get me wrong: this is not pushing for anything to happen, it is really about *understanding* the current situation, and what it means for our "joint journey".</sub>

Comment: To be clear, we're all still working. Instead of some folks being in the office, everyone is working from home.

Comment: Sure, that is true for many companies. That doesn't necessarily mean that plans are executed as planned. I see that in my own company in plenty of places.

Comment: Seems to me this was largely covered by [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/09/a-message-to-our-employees-community-and-customers-on-covid-19/)

Comment: well, even 5 days make a difference by now. Between "maybe we just work all from home" and "full national lock down".

Comment: Worth noting that even without the virus, many employees are remote.

Comment: @Taryn well the problematic thing, at least in Israel, is the total shut down of the education system. Parents need to spend time keeping watch on their child(ren), thus work is cut in half for many, even if they can work from home.

Comment: Exactly. And when people have to worry about getting food, or other essential stuff, or sick family... There are so many things that might require ones focus and energy. If this would only be about sitting behind a different desk, the Dow wouldn't have lost thousands of points...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Stack Exchange, Inc. becomes busier with supporting Stack Overflow for Teams because more companies start using it due to lockdowns.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you pointed out, things have changed. All Stack employees are now working from home. And while this isn’t a big change for many of our employees, most of us now have additional factors to contend with that can end up reducing our ability to move forward with different initiatives at the rate that we had intended and committed to. And we are fortunate to work for a company that has made employee physical and mental health an absolute top priority.

I tried to address this a little in the feature preview post on [Question Following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions) the other day:

> (Work is well underway, and we are aiming for a release by the end of March. However, [current events](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/09/a-message-to-our-employees-community-and-customers-on-covid-19/) make it likely that delays may be introduced into the process, so it is hard to give an exact commitment right now).

We do intend to follow up on the different items in the Q1 Roadmap. And as part of our commitment to open communication, we will try to communicate as best as we can if and when plans or commitments are delayed.

We thank you for your understanding and support.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. Best wishes, stay healthy!