# New [mod-agreement-policy] tag has an incorrect description

Tags: bug, tags, edits, moderator-agreement

Today a new moderator only tag was [introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350544/the-new-moderator-agreement-is-now-live-for-moderators-to-accept-across-the-netw): [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy).

Its tag description states:

> Use this tag to indicate posts that are official Stack Exchange policy that moderators are expected to abide by. These posts can only be edited by staff members.

Which to me would indicate that I should technically not be able to edit any post with this tag.
However I just [managed to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/336173/revisions) on this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336173/what-processes-exist-to-issue-formal-warnings-or-remove-moderators).

- Is the technical implementation not working as intended, or is the tag description not in line with the reality?
- Should all posts tagged [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) also be manually locked with the new "[Policy Lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349276/new-post-lock-available-on-meta-sites-policy-lock)"?

Comment: I already suggested an edit to fix it.

Comment: @pppery your suggested edit would make things consistent with the current behaviour, but I doubt your edit is desired. I think the current behaviour is not as intended. If it is as intended but people **should** not edit those posts, the tag description needs tweaking, other then your suggestion.

Comment: @pppery: that.... was not the best course of action. Lets see what staff say is the correct text, shall we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no technical implementation. The posts have to be manually locked. The information is in the tag wiki excerpt because it is a defining trait of items in that tag but we don't have a way of applying it automatically. The other thing to consider is that the policies are often the answers, not the questions, so we wouldn't want to automate this, anyway.

I've added the locks to the policies now.