# Answer delete votes not showing up

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, vote-to-delete

I voted to delete [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91704/whats-got-into-the-question-closers-recently/91706#91706), but the delete button just says "delete" instead of "delete (1)". If I try to vote again, it correctly tells me that I've already voted, so this must be a UI issue.

Comment: I can repro this. I voted myself. The screen said `delete (2)` after I voted, but on refresh, it was back to `delete`. Before I voted, it did not say `delete (1)`, either.

Comment: I can't delete answers on meta `:(` I'm very sad.

Comment: I deleted it, so I must have cast the proverbial third vote, even though it did not say `delete(2)` as it should have.

Comment: @jjn It's only 1.4k left to go, you'll be there soon. ♪

Comment: @Grace, I was at 20k before questions were made 5 rep network-wide.  I feel like I was demoted.

Comment: @jjn That explains the discrepancy. I was wondering how you were still under 20k, when it was many months ago that you made that push for 10k.

Comment: @Grace, yeah unfortunately I had lots of questions with upvotes.  I lost ~3k rep that fateful day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a deferred execution bug in the preloading code for deletion votes, it's fixed in the next build.